# Sails.js how to set up HTML 5 App-Cache?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sails.js, html5-appcache

Anyone know of a guide, sample project, blog post, or something in the Sails docs about the best practice for configuring the app-cache?

Cheers,

JL